# Switching opacity using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, opacity

Why `.delay` doesn't work in my code?
Code should

1. Switch opacity of `.sample` to 0
2. Wait 2s (using `.delay`) and than add class `.bg_color`
3. Wait 2s and than switch opacity of `.sample` back to 1

**HTML**

```
<div class="sample"></div><br><br><br>
<button class="btn_1">Change</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.sample{
    padding:20px;
    background:skyblue;
    float:left;
}
.bg_color{
    background:red;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn_1").click(function(){
      $(".sample").css("opacity","0");
        $(".sample").delay(1000).addClass("bg_color");
        $(".sample").delay(1000).css("opacity","1");

    });
});
```

U can find my Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/okkuvep7/)

Comment: As the docs state: The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the setTimeout : http://jsfiddle.net/okkuvep7/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn_1").click(function(){
      $(".sample").css("opacity","0");

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".sample").addClass("bg_color");
            $(".sample").css("opacity","1");        
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```